# How to use clearInterval?

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and try to send message to the server.

When I input 1, it will set message to the server every 3 second. When I input 2, it will stop sending the message.

However, it keeps sending message to the server when I input 2. How should I use  clearInterval

this is the script.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8075");

ws.onopen = ('connect', function(connect) {
  let obj={};
  obj.body='connect';
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
});

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (message) {
    if (message.trim() == '1') {
            var setintv = setInterval(function () {
                let obj2 = {};
                obj2.name = 'data'
                message = '123';
                obj2.body = message;
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj2), console.log.bind(null, 'Sent : ', message));
        }, 3000);
}else if(message.trim() == '2') {
    clearInterval(setintv);
}
else {
    let obj = {};
    obj.name = 'data'
    message = message.trim();
    obj.body = message;
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj), console.log.bind(null, 'Sent : ', message));
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable setintv will not be available in the block where you call clearInterval. If you however declare it as a global it will be, for example:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8075");

ws.onopen = ('connect', function(connect) {
  let obj={};
  obj.body='connect';
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
});

var setintv = null;

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (message) {
    if (message.trim() == '1') {
        // Save for later use.
        setintv = setInterval(function () {
                let obj2 = {};
                obj2.name = 'data'
                message = '123';
                obj2.body = message;
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj2), console.log.bind(null, 'Sent : ', message));
        }, 3000);
}else if(message.trim() == '2') {
    if (setintv !== null) {
        clearInterval(setintv);
        setintv = null; // We're done with this now.
    }
}
else {
    let obj = {};
    obj.name = 'data'
    message = message.trim();
    obj.body = message;
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj), console.log.bind(null, 'Sent : ', message));
}
});
```